# In what platforms/browsers does Adobe Flash come preinstalled?

Tags: flash, browser

In what platforms/browsers does Adobe Flash come preinstalled?

I'm pretty sure neither FireFox nor Safari include it on any platform but Chrome on Windows does (not sure about Mac or Linux).

What about IE on a completely vanilla Win XP system? Or Win 7? Maybe mfgs like Dell add it if MS doesn't? Perhaps we can find (or build) a comprehensive list.

Considering that Flash is a significant piece of the web platform, I hope I've asked this on the right place.

Comment: Flash doesn't come preinstalled on new Macbook Airs.

Comment: @Muhammad, that's actually the news that led me to ask this question. Does it come installed on non-Air macbooks?

Comment: Its not on Win7 by default either, at least it wasn't on my Toshiba.

Answer (score 1):

I bought a Macbook Pro (13") last month so it's the newest generation and it didn't come installed with Flash at all. I just went ahead and installed Flash for Chrome and Firefox, I don't remember installing it for Safari.

On Android it comes installed.

Comment: On Windows, at least, there is Flash for IE, flash built into Google Chrome, and one other flash shared between browsers (FF, Opera, Safari when Safari ran on Windows, SeaMonkey, ...). It could be that installing it for FF also installed it for Safari.